# Parsing a list in Python

Tags: python, list, parsing, monkeylearn

I am trying sentiment analysis with **MONKEYLEARN API** in python.

When I print the result I get the following response.

```
[{'text': 'Today is a very good weather', 'external_id': None,'error': False, 'classifications': [{'tag_name': 'Positive', 'tag_id':60333048, 'confidence': 0.987}]}]
```

The result if of type `list` and I want to isolate only the **classification** results from this list that is the

**TAG_NAME: Positive** and the **Confidence: 0.987**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The "classifications" field already is a list. You can just do result['classifications'] to retrieve it (it is a dictionary)

Comment: @anerisgreat not exactly, the result is actually a dict inside a list.

Comment: @CorentinPane good point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Say you are getting the response like this:

```
lst = [{'text': 'Today is a very good weather', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': [{'tag_name': 'Positive', 'tag_id': 60333048, 'confidence': 0.987}]}]
```

Do this:

```
classification_result = lst[0]['classifications'][0]
tag_name = classification_result['tag_name']
confidence = classification_result['confidence']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    result = [{'text': 'Today is a very good weather', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': [{'tag_name': 'Positive', 'tag_id': 60333048, 'confidence': 0.987}]}]
    classification_result = result[0].get("classifications")[0]
```

Now this is dictionary from which following can get gathered:

- tag_name using classification_result["tag_name"]
- tag_id using classification_result["tag_id"]
- confidence using classification_result["confidence"]

it is nested dictionary inside list, and list inside dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Just get the element you from the list and then select `classification`.
You can easily this if you print your list.

```
your_list = [{'text': 'Today is a very good weather', 'external_id': None,'error': False, 'classifications': [{'tag_name': 'Positive', 'tag_id':60333048, 'confidence': 0.987}]}]
print(your_list)
#output
[{'text': 'Today is a very good weather',
  'external_id': None,
  'error': False,
  'classifications': [{'tag_name': 'Positive',
    'tag_id': 60333048,
    'confidence': 0.987}]}]
```

Then do this

```
your_list[0]['classifications']
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers worked efficietly. 
I went with answer by AVION and Sayandip Dutta.

```
classification_result = lst[0]['classifications'][0]
tag_name = classification_result['tag_name']
confidence = classification_result['confidence']
```